# How to force hibernate to do join while using @OneToOne mapping with @MapsId

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class MappedChild {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Long parentId;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @MapsId
    private MappedParent mappedParent;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class MappedParent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Long parentId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "mappedParent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private MappedChild mappedChild;
}
```

And when I'm loading `MappedChild`, I'm expecting to hibernate to make JOIN for retrieving `MappedParent`. But actually hibernate does two selects, one for `MappedChild`, and one for `MappedParent`. I have tried to change the child mapping to next:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class MappedChild {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "child_id")
    private Long childId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn("parent_id")
    private MappedParent mappedParent;
}
```

And after that it works as expected: hibernate does JOIN instead of two selects. But that is not what I want, I don't need two separate ids in the child (child_id and parent_id), because it is excess for mine case. Can I modify the first mapping and make hibernate do JOIN instead of two selects?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, If I am not able to correctly perceive your question.
However from what I could collect, you can try using `@Fetch` annotation.

**Syntax**:

> > @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)

You can use this in your entity class ,for example:

```
  @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @MapsId
    private MappedParent mappedParent;
```

Moreover, I guess `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` would be unnecessary in this case as `@MapsId` already accomplishes the job .

Please give me a deeper insight of the question if I am perceiving it wrong.
Would love further queries from you.

ThankYou

Comment: Hibernate documentation says, that `Eager` fetch type and `Join` fetch mode is the default for `@OneToOne`. But even if I add these annotations - it doesn't make any effect, hibernate continue using two selects instead of the join. As a quick fix, I have overcome this by using HQL with `JOIN FETCH`. But I'm still interesting about this behavior, it looks weird.